# Looking up for an item in a list and different table styles in iOS

Tags: search, tables, ios, selection, human-interface-guideline

I have a settings view with a grouped table. One of the cells of such table is intended to show a very long list of items from where I want the user to select one. Due to the length of the list, I need to provide a way to make easier to find a certain item.

One of the options I think there are, is to show letters of alphabet as indexes at the right side of a plain table. Since my first table is a grouped one, my navigation hierarchy would be then like this:

[image: iPhone_grouped]  [image: iPhone_plain]

Would it be inconsistent to navigate from a grouped table to a plain table? If so, could somebody give an existing example? I didn't find anything related to this in iOS Human Interface Guidelines, maybe it is described somewhere else and this navigation pattern breaks the guidelines.

Another option could be having a search bar. Can a search bar be used in both a plain table and a grouped table? The existing example of such bar I found is in Contacts app and it is a plain table. In a plain table, could both an alphabet index and a search bar be shown?

Answer (score 1):

Users a tend to remember list structure, so it is not a good idea to reorder it. I would say the following:

- long lists are not that good
- search field is a bad idea (usually the user doesn't know what to search)
- complex components (list withing a cell of the treetable) do not usually work well

Please check [Miller columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns) and [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16974/whats-is-the-best-ui-interface-for-permission) topic. I will also add list of options from [my other answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/42847/21423):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I try to avoid very long lists of items, but this one is a requirement I've been given and I can`t omit information. I think I'd be able to show something like Miller columns in iPad version, but I don´t know how I could handle any of your options in iPhone...

Comment: Approach with Miller columns seems to be native for iOS. Here is an example: http://www.maclife.com/files/u129772/restrictions_only_0.jpg But due to screen size limitations it is rendered as #6

Comment: You're right, I was thinking about displaying a split view... this is what I do with first level of my settings menu, but then when I need to show the long list of selectable items, I have no way to categorize them into smaller groups further than alphabetical

Comment: I would recommend not to use option 2 and 4 in this case, in which the requirement is to show a long list. Expanding one menu item would put the other top menu items too far away.

Answer (score 0):

### IDEA 1: Grouping

Can you ***group items in the second table*** (plain table) further? If so, the interface is much simplified.

### IDEA 2: Filtering

If *IDEA 1* is impossible to follow, then you can do another thing. ***Implement a filter feature*** to the long list. Just place an icon at the top of the list. Clicking on it should bring a new page. Provide checkboxes, sliders, or some other facility according to your situation. ***Avoid the search bar if possible*** -- users don't know what words you have used in your list.

### IDEA 3: Sorting

If *IDEA 2* fails, then you must sort and present the list manually. Think about the options again and decide ***which are the most used options?*** Guess what most users want. Show those options first!

### IDEA 4: Visual cues

Use icons or pictures relating to the actions/properties of the items in the list. This allows easy scanning.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm afraid the only filter I could apply in this case is alphabetical, I haven't any other grouping criteria. Since plain tables in iOS could show an alphabetical index, but ASFAIK grouped tables can't, I need someone to tell me if it may result inconsistent to navigate from a view with a grouped table to a view with a plain table

Answer (score 0):

You already named the best solution: Search. Just look at the Contacts app. There is a global search for all contact groups and a search for just a group at a time.

Don't think about about the implementation while finding the best UI/problem solution. Ignore the code. UI design first. Otherwise you limit yourself finding the best solution for the user.